# Angular Pie chart

Tags: angular, pie-chart

Using which angular package we can design this kind of pie charts?

**[PIE Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grZhX.png)**(Open this for pie chart model)

Note: **Need labels in the same way**

Thanks in advance

Comment: check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-highcharts

Comment: Any open source one ?@Rahul

Comment: It's open source

Answer (score -1):

Use nvd3 library, very simple to use and easy to inject on your controller.

here's a example to understand

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.options = {
            chart: {
                type: 'pieChart',
                height: 450,
                donut: true,
                x: function(d){return d.key;},
                y: function(d){return d.y;},
                showLabels: true,
                labelsOutside: true,
                pie: {
                    startAngle: function(d) { return d.startAngle/2 -Math.PI/2 },
                    endAngle: function(d) { return d.endAngle/2 -Math.PI/2 }
                },
                duration: 500,
                legend: {
                    margin: {
                        top: 5,
                        right: 70,
                        bottom: 5,
                        left: 0
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        $scope.data = [
            {
                key: "One",
                y: 5
            },
            {
                key: "Two",
                y: 2
            },
            {
                key: "Three",
                y: 9
            },
            {
                key: "Four",
                y: 7
            },
            {
                key: "Five",
                y: 4
            },
            {
                key: "Six",
                y: 3
            },
            {
                key: "Seven",
                y: .5
            }
        ];
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/OlROrZ?p=preview